# Dynamically assign ViewModel to View at Runtime MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a View in an MVC 5 application that has lots of form fields.  For different requests, I use the same View but different strongly-typed ViewModels.  Each ViewModel has the exact same fields, but the required fields are different for each type of request.

My question is can I dynamically assign a strongly-typed ViewModel at runtime depending on the scenario?  I am trying to avoid copying the same View for each scenario, because the View will remain consistent no matter the number of scenarios that present themselves.

For example, I want to assign one of the ViewModels below to the View I have created, depending on which scenario is chosen:

```
public class FirstScenario_ViewModel
{
     [Required]
     string FirstValue {get; set;}

     string SecondValue {get; set;}
}

public class SecondScenario_ViewModel
{
     string FirstValue {get; set;}

     [Required]
     string SecondValue {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: One option is to use a single model/view/action method with conditional validation attributes, for example using [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar type attributes. Another is to use a 'base' class/interface for the model, and then create a custom `ModelBinder` to generate the concrete class in the POST method.

Comment: Awesome!   Thanks guys!  I went the foolproof route due to a tight deadline, but these were all good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to reuse the view passing different subclasses.
Razor will even recognize the attributes and populate the html according to the concrete type sent to the view.

Subclassing is only part of the solution. The second part is the model binding that needs to happen once the form is posted.
You can address this by creating a custom model binder as mentioned in one of the comments.
Another one is to tweak the form's action so that the form gets posted to a action that can handle the correct viewmodel type. The advantage of having multiple actions is that it becomes trivial to implement custom validation on the action.

Using multiple actions might not be the most elegant solution. I am not sure if there are any bad side effects.

Below is a sample view model:

```
// This is the base class declared as the view's @model
// This one would have all the common validations
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string ModelType { get; set; }
    public virtual string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel1 : TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public override string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel2 : TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public override string Prop1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller:

```
  public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Edit(string modelType)
    {
        if (modelType == "1") return View(new Models.TestViewModel1() {ModelType = "1"});
        if (modelType == "2") return View(new Models.TestViewModel2() {ModelType = "2" });
        return View(new Models.TestViewModel() { ModelType = "" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Models.TestViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.Prop1 == null) ModelState.AddModelError("Prop1", "Please type something");
        if (ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Edit");
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit1(Models.TestViewModel1 model)
    {
        if (model.Prop1 == null || !model.Prop1.Contains("1")) ModelState.AddModelError("Prop1", "Please type at least one character 1");
        if (ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { modelType = "1" });
        return View("Edit", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit2(Models.TestViewModel2 model)
    {
        if (model.Prop2 == null || !model.Prop1.Contains("2")) ModelState.AddModelError("Prop2", "Please type at least one character 2");
        if (ModelState.IsValid) return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { modelType = "2"});
        return View("Edit", model);
    }
}
```

and the view (look at **@using (Html.BeginForm..**):

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.TestViewModel
@{
   Layout = null;
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit" + Model.ModelType, "Test", new {Model.ModelType}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>TestModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @DateTime.Now.ToString("o")
        <br/>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelType)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ModelType)
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prop1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prop1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prop2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prop2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prop3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prop3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prop3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```